# sqlite database hardcode /data/ db_path android

Tags: android, database, sqliteopenhelper

Cannot retrieve database, and shows a lint warning that says:

```
Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead
```

Have tried searching for related errors but nothing helps. 
Here's the code

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/mlearning.fundprog/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "questionsDb";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + context.getPackageName() + DB_NAME;
}   

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}
```

I really dont get what's wrong with this. It was working before, but i'm thinking it's because i have moved to API 14 from API 8. I guess this higher API has another rule for codings. Is that so?

Comment: Are you actually using `DB_PATH` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, Im using `DB_PATH` everywhere @CL.

Comment: Not in the code you've shown. (The `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor sees only `DB_NAME`.)

Comment: I've added more code in the post @CL

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Better use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Answer (score 3):

To get the path to a database, [use `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below 2 methods to get the path of your database:

- `DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases";`

or use this

- `DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent();`

Comment: What does `v` in `v.getDatabasePath` stands for?

Comment: That should be placed inside the DBHelper constructor right? I've tried it and still doesn't work

Comment: Yes. Try debugfing ur app and see waht contains DB PATH